# Excel interpolation with a few cells of same values in consecutive order

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

the data I'm trying to interpolate looks like this:

```
=X= 
0
0
0
0
0
0.5
1
3.1
5.5
6.2
8.5

=Y=
0.019607843
0.019607843
0.019607843
0.019607843
0.019607843
0.117647059
0.137254902
0.156862745
0.176470588
0.196078431
0.215686275

=Z=
0.019607843
0.039215686
0.058823529
0.078431373
0.098039216
0.117647059
0.137254902
0.156862745
0.176470588
0.196078431
0.215686275
0.235294118
```

I'm using the http://www.xlxtrfun.com/XlXtrFun/XlXtrFun.htm addin. In a cell I have the interpolation formula from this addin, it works correctly most of the time except with this particular set of data.

in **AM1** I have this code:

> =Interpolate($F$2:$F$51,$D$2:$D$51,M2,TRUE,FALSE)

where column F is the Y Data D is the X data and M is Z

the problem with it is that in the X set of data there is consecutive values of 0, so in the cell with the formula I get a **#NUM!**

I tried altering the 0's slightly to 0.1 0.2 etc. after that it works correctly so I know the formula is right, however with this data I can't alter it or it will drastically change results in the end. So does anyone know of a way I can keep these values and keep a correct interpolation?

Comment: What happens if you swap say X and Z in the inputs? From the example on there site there Y has repeated values (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2) so maybe it just doesn't like the 'independent' variable to have repeats. By swapping X and Z you might be able to trick it into looking more like that example? Then you just have to make sure you read the X values off the Z output etc...

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. That's not always an option as well because in some instances when I'm using the formula the x and z datasets are different sizes.

Comment: Are you doing 1d or 2d interpolation? I'm assuming 1d as in you want to find the X values at specific Y points (which you have called Z for some reason)? Since your first 5 values not only have the same X values but also the same Y values you could always just not include 4 of them?

Comment: Also does interpolate expect X or Y values first? Can't see the docs online, is it =interpolate(Xin, Yin, xout, ? ?) or =interpolate(Yin, Xin, xout, ? ?) ? Because your Y is really what they are seeing as X, so make sure not to mix them up. i.e. for your formula to be correct, interpolate() must expect inputs in the first form in this comment not the second.

Comment: +1 for asking a question coz it seemed like VBA tag had lost interesting questions for sometime... :) Well as for the interpol part.. Isn't supposed to have `x, y, interpol point, interpol type(e.g. linear, cubic)` as basic parameters? But this function is doing cubic and double parabolic and there's no space for Linear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In anycase if you want to try the **above formula as a VBA function** (so to keep your sheet clean)...you may give a try on the following. Perhaps it's a day I don't want to write more codes ;) So it works in my end. And if it does for you then all thanks to [Tushar Mehta](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/interpolation/index.html) LOL I just copied that tag line from @pnuts.. However in the above site you have more codes related to interpol. Do give it a try as well.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Function RealEqual(X, Y) As Boolean
    RealEqual = Abs(X - Y) <= 0.00000001
End Function

Function LinearInterp(XVals, YVals, TargetVal)
   Dim MatchVal
   On Error GoTo ErrXit

   With Application.WorksheetFunction
    MatchVal = .Match(TargetVal, XVals, 1)
     If MatchVal = XVals.Cells.Count _
            And RealEqual(TargetVal, .Index(XVals, MatchVal)) Then
        LinearInterp = .Index(YVals, MatchVal)
     Else
        LinearInterp = .Index(YVals, MatchVal) _
            + (.Index(YVals, MatchVal + 1) - .Index(YVals, MatchVal)) _
                / (.Index(XVals, MatchVal + 1) _
                    - .Index(XVals, MatchVal)) _
                * (TargetVal - .Index(XVals, MatchVal))
     End If
   End With
    Exit Function
ErrXit:
    With Err
     LinearInterp = .Description & "(Number= " & .Number & ")"
    End With
End Function
```

Sheet view:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AndrewConnelly glad you got it worked out :) Check on the other functions in that site, it has both cubic and parabolic as well.

Answer (score 1):

For linear interpolation I think this formula works (copied down as appropriate):

```
=   INDEX(F$6:F$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16))+ 
(M6-INDEX(D$6:D$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16)))*INDEX(F$6:F$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16)+1)-  
    INDEX(F$6:F$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16)))/(INDEX(D$6:D$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16)+1)-  
    INDEX(D$6:D$16,MATCH(M6,D$6:D$16)))
```

[image: SO14272723 example]

IF it does, full credit to [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-interpolation-formulas/) (otherwise blame is all mine only!)